# laravel 5.2 session not persist on route change

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

> laravel 5.2 session not persist after route change,

I have not used any middleware. session returns all values in controller  when i put session but it forgets when redirect to another route.

> here  is my routes

```
Route::auth();

Route::get('login','LoginController@login');

Route::post('login','LoginController@check');

Route::get('/','HomeController@index');

Route::post('school/store','HomeController@store');
```

Comment: Use session save.

Comment: i have tried that too, not working  if fount this      https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-sessions-dont-persist?page=1       link  which says we need to use web middleware to start session is it needed really ? 
i have also tried to put all my routes in web middleware but not working, do i need to create middleware using artisan?

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.2, everything need to be given a web middleware in order to use cookies or sessions. It is not mentioned in Laravel upgrade guide though.

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/middleware-groups-in-laravel-5-2

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13000

Comment: do i need to create middleware using command or just put 
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {

//routes

 }); as above?

Comment: just  use the web middleware it, if others you have to create them.

Comment: Route::auth();


Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => 'web'], function () {   
  

Route::get('/','HomeController@index');

//routes
}); its still not working!!

Comment: it is in web middleware,can it be due to i have disabled csrf token in kernel.php and used it in form?